# why cant i change data type of a column in python even after using 'astype'

Tags: python, types, pandas

i have a dataframe 'df' as such

```
a= (0,1,2,3...)
b = ('blue', 'red', 'brown', 'black')
c = ('new york', 'phoenix', 'chicago', 'orlando')
d = ('ny', 'phx', 'chi', 'ord')
```

i have a function func(d) that requires a string or unicode object
as the type of the argument d

for example: df['d'] = func(df['d'])

(i want the function func() to operate on each item in the d column)

how can i convert column 'd' to a string or unicode? its currently a series and I get the
error "TypeError: expected string or Unicode object, Series found"

I have tried using astype(str) but this doesnt seem to have any affect.

Comment: What is a dataframe? What library/import are you using to create it?

Comment: How does the variable `df` relate to your four variables a,b,c, and d?

Comment: I think you want to do `df['d'].apply(func)` but it's difficult to say without data and your code for dunc

Comment: a,b,c,d are the column names

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, your function probably doesn't support sequences of strings as input, only strings.  You can use `apply` to pass the values individually:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"d": ['ny', 'phx', 'chi', 'ord']})
>>> def func(x): return x.upper()
>>> df
     d
0   ny
1  phx
2  chi
3  ord

[4 rows x 1 columns]
>>> df["d"] = df["d"].apply(func)
>>> df
     d
0   NY
1  PHX
2  CHI
3  ORD

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```